# Toggle links globally using macro

Tags: macros, moderncv, links

I'm writing a CV for my wife using [moderncv](https://launchpad.net/moderncv/+download). We're not sure whether her supervisor wants links in the document, so every time a link might be required, I write the text twice:

```
PhD student at the Weizmann Institute of Science
% PhD student at the \textcolor{cyan}{\href{http://www.weizmann.ac.il/}{Weizmann Institute of Science}}}
```

If the tutor decides that we should use links, I will comment out the unlinke text:

```
% PhD student at the Weizmann Institute of Science
PhD student at the \textcolor{cyan}{\href{http://www.weizmann.ac.il/}{Weizmann Institute of Science}}}
```

I don't like [duplicating code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), so I was looking for a way to define a Tex macro for my link style. Perhaps something like:

```
PhD student at the {\myhref{http://www.weizmann.ac.il/}{Weizmann Institute of Science}}
```

Where `\myhref` is defined once at the top, where I can toggle the links on and off, and set the link colors if they exist.

Is there a way to define a global, custom macro in tex?

Comment: IMHO, just put the links, but color them black; they will still work, but won't impact the printed document. In any case, you will need to pick darker colors than the horrible default ones…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is all I can say without an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Maybe it works for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref, etoolbox}

\newtoggle{supervisor}
%\toggletrue{supervisor}

\newcommand{\myhref}[2]{%
  \iftoggle{supervisor}%
    {\href{#1}{#2}}%
    {#2}%
}

\begin{document}
PhD student at the \myhref{http://www.weizmann.ac.il/}{Weizmann Institute of Science}
\end{document}
```

As for the link color, I suggest you use the options provided by hyperref (`colorlinks`, `urlcolor` etc.)

Answer (score 5):

This should work.

```
%% With link
\newcommand{\myhref}[2]{%
  \textcolor{cyan}{\href{#1}{#2}}}

%% Without link
% \newcommand{\myhref}[2]{#2}
```